# Ngnix redirect for multilevel subdirectories

Tags: linux, nginx, 301-redirect

I have URL like the following structure:

```
xyz/asset.html
abc/test.html
xyz/abc/test.html
xyz/abc/qwerty/test2.html
```

I would like to redirect:

`xyz/asset.html to xyz/asset`

`xyz/abc/test.html to xyz/abc/test`

`xyz/abc/qwerty/test2.html to xyz/abc/qwerty/test2`

Currently I've this redirect rule in my ngnix configuration and it's working for the first level directory redirect:

```
location ~ ^/(xyz|abc).html { return 301 /$1; }
```

This works for first level of direct but not working  for  subdirectories. How to achieve this? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this. Here's one such way...

The first step is to capture the part of the URI that needs to rewritten. Then, we can do the redirection using either a `location` block or using `rewrite` condition.

Using `location` block with `named capture`...

```
location ~ ^/(?<variable>[/a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ { return 301 /$variable; }
```

Or

```
location ~ ^/([/a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ { return 301 /$1; }
```

Using `rewrite`...

```
rewrite ^/(?'custom_url'[/a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.html$ /$custom_url permanent;
```

Nginx supports `named captures` using the following syntax:

```
?<name>     Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?'name'     Perl 5.10 compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-7.0
?P<name>    Python compatible syntax, supported since PCRE-4.0
```

Ref: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html (under the header **Regular expressions names**).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pothi. I tried the location rule you provided. It's working for 2nd level sub-dir (xyz/abc/test.html to xyz/abc/test) but not for (yz/abc/qwerty/test2.html to xyz/abc/qwerty/test2).

Comment: If you used `location` rule, then please make sure to have a default `location` rule as well such as `location / {}`. Here's the sample repo to test the above scenario with the test URL available (temporarily for now)... https://github.com/pothi/qa-nginx/tree/main/serverfault/1070388

Comment: Thanks mate! That was helpful. It worked.